# antialiasing not working in babylon js

Tags: babylonjs

I am trying to apply antialiasing to my scene. This is the code I use:

```
var postProcess = new BABYLON.FxaaPostProcess("fxaa", 1.0, null, null, engine, true);
```

The object is still jagged. Any idea how to make it smoother?

[image]

Full code:

```
var canvas;
var engine;

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    canvas = document.getElementById("renderCanvas");
    engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true);

    var createScene = function () {
        var scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);
        scene.clearColor = new BABYLON.Color3(0, 1, 0);
        var camera = new BABYLON.FreeCamera("camera1", new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 5, -10), scene);
        camera.attachControl(canvas, false);
        var light = new BABYLON.HemisphericLight("light1", new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 1, 0), scene);
        light.intensity = 1.88;

        var box = BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh("box", "", "box.babylon", scene, function (newMeshes, particleSystems) {
            newMeshes.position = new BABYLON.Vector3(0,0,0);

        });
        var postProcess = new BABYLON.FxaaPostProcess("fxaa", 1.0, null, null, engine, true);

        return scene;

    };
    var scene = createScene();
    engine.runRenderLoop(function () {
        scene.render();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We reworked the FXAA in 3.0. Did you try the new version? Available here: https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js/tree/master/dist/preview%20release